# Mongoose, define a OR ref in schema(enum)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```
 thread = new mongoose.Schema({
    post: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'},
    comment: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'},
 })
```

But in fact, thread can only have post or comment, it cannot have both at same time.

so ideal definition should be something like enum

```
 thread = new mongoose.Schema({
    data: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'} OR?? {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'},
 })
```

How can I define this kind of thing in Mongoose?

Or what is the right way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: What abou this: `data: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: { type: String, enum: ['Post', 'Comment'] } }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is discriminators. This of course actually refers to the same "core" model, but it's handled in a special way so that different types of objects are distinquished and even considered to have their own model.

As an example listing for usage:

```
var async = require('async'),
    util = require('util'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/content');

mongoose.set("debug",true);

function BaseSchema() {
  Schema.apply(this,arguments);

  this.add({
    "author": String,
    "body": String,
    "created": { "type": Date, "default": Date.now() }
  });
}

util.inherits(BaseSchema,Schema);

var itemSchema = new BaseSchema();

var postSchema = new BaseSchema({
  "title": String,
  "score": Number
});

var commentSchema = new BaseSchema({
  "post": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Post" }
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item',itemSchema),
    Post = Item.discriminator('Post',postSchema),
    Comment = Item.discriminator('Comment',commentSchema);

async.series(
  [
    // Clean data
    function(callback) {
      Item.remove({},callback);
    },

    // Insert Post
    function(callback) {
      async.waterfall(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Post.create({
              "title": "This post",
              "author": "bill",
              "body": "Whoa!"
            },callback);
          },
          function(post,callback) {
            Comment.create({
              "author": "ted",
              "body": "Excellent!",
              "post": post
            },callback);
          }
        ],
        callback
      );
    },

    function(callback) {
      console.log("All Items");
      Item.find().exec(function(err,docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        callback(err);
      })
    },

    function(callback) {
      console.log("Just populated Comments");
      Comment.find().populate('post').exec(function(err,docs) {
        console.log(docs)
        callback(err);
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

And the output:

```
All Items
Mongoose: items.find({}) { fields: undefined }
[ { created: Wed Mar 16 2016 14:15:56 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
    __t: 'Post',
    __v: 0,
    body: 'Whoa!',
    author: 'bill',
    title: 'This post',
    _id: 56e8cfed833e67750b678d9c },
  { created: Wed Mar 16 2016 14:15:56 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
    __t: 'Comment',
    __v: 0,
    post: 56e8cfed833e67750b678d9c,
    body: 'Excellent!',
    author: 'ted',
    _id: 56e8cfed833e67750b678d9d } ]
Just populated Comments
Mongoose: items.find({ __t: 'Comment' }) { fields: undefined }
Mongoose: items.find({ __t: 'Post', _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("56e8cfed833e67750b678d9c") ] } }) { fields: undefined }
[ { created: Wed Mar 16 2016 14:15:56 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
    __t: 'Comment',
    __v: 0,
    post:
     { created: Wed Mar 16 2016 14:15:56 GMT+1100 (AEDT),
       __t: 'Post',
       __v: 0,
       body: 'Whoa!',
       author: 'bill',
       title: 'This post',
       _id: 56e8cfed833e67750b678d9c },
    body: 'Excellent!',
    author: 'ted',
    _id: 56e8cfed833e67750b678d9d } ]
```

If you look through the listing what you see is that we do indeed create a single model for `Item` which is going to hold all objects, but the most interesting thing happens on the following lines:

```
var Item = mongoose.model('Item',itemSchema),
    Post = Item.discriminator('Post',postSchema),
    Comment = Item.discriminator('Comment',commentSchema);
```

So instead of using `mongoose.model` for the next two model definitions we call `Item.discriminator()` instead. This creates "special models" that will be contained within `Item` and of course each type has it's own attached schema, and any logic that would be associated with that schema.

Since all data is actually in the same collection, even though we use each model seperately, you see that there is a special key addded to each object as `__t`. This contains the registered name of the model that the data is actually associated with.

The the `"debug"` option set, you can see how mongoose actually issues the queries. So when you just want to work on `Comment`, the `__t` value is automatically added to the query conditions ( and object creation of course ). In the same case where we asked "comments" to contain a reference to `Post`, the same sort of filtering is applied when looking for things that should be referenced in the `Post` model.

This is a pretty powerful pattern, and can either also employ the same sort of inheritance as demonstrated here or alternately just base of a completely blank or seperate schema definition.

If it were just a field for "reference" to data in this collection. Then using the base model of `Item` in a foreign collection has the same result.

```
var otherSchema = new Schema({
    "item": { "type": Schema.Types.ObjectId, "ref": "Item" }
});

mongoose.model("Other",otherSchema);

mongoose.model("Other").find().populate("item").exec(function(err,docs( {
    // populates references with either Comment or Post
    // as per their assigned __t value
});
```

If the referenced item is a `Comment`, then it gets all the attached benefits of the coments schema. Or if it is a `Post`, then you see the same first class object treatment.

So whatever way you want to use it, once defined using a discriminator then mongoose will work it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref

Dynamic References via `refPath` allow to do what you want

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although it can point the OP to an answer, it is better to exemplify with some code that show why your point is better than the already answered and accepted answer, so many years after. Otherwise, your answer is almost a comment..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32993313)